# Remove cells greater than a number in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I think this should be rather simple, but maybe I'm missing something. Basically I'd like to remove outliers from a column, without deleting the entire row. I've got a big data set with 2,000 some odd rows, and about 20 columns of numbers. I know I can do an advanced filter with those column titles, and use a formula to get my greater than numbers for all of them rapidly, but the advanced filter will remove the entire row.

I'd like to simply remove the contents of that cell if it's greater than a certain number. I can do something like create a column beside the column, and `=if(A2>=Y2, "",A2)`, drag down for the 2,000 values, and then just replace the original column, but that's a lot of work!

Is there something like advanced filter that will only remove the contents of the cell in that column, rather than the entire row?

Here's a quick example of what my data would look like (not actually my data, we have more alligator wrasslers in there), and I'm only worried about taking out the high outliers with my data set (though something that removed above a certain number and below a certain number would be great too!)
[image]

Comment: Unless you do each column like you say, I'm afraid you'll need an VBA solution for this. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uy1_nOkj648  Maybe resume data with Pivot Tables?

Comment: Step back:  Why do you need to remove the cells?  Perhaps, if you are analyzing the data, a better solution would be to just use an appropriate formula to exclude the values you wish to exclude?

Comment: You could use conditional formatting to hide the number, but that wouldn't remove it from any calculations.

Comment: After removing outliers I need to run some statistical analysis on it - it's basically participants in a program to lose weight, with some being successful, and some not. The columns are things they did during the period in which the program ran, so after splitting them into successful and unsuccessful, I need to analyze what each group did, run T-tails/Kruskall Wallis/Chi square depending on what the data looks like, go from there basically. Don't think excel's data analysis add in has filters for what you describe in it's stats test, and neither does xrealstats.

Comment: Thanks Foxfire, I'd found this page on a quick module to remove numbers with a macro: https://www.excelbanter.com/excel-worksheet-functions/216453-deleting-values-less-than-100-a.html
I was just hoping that there was an automated way to do it :) . If not, thanks anyways, appreciate the comments guys!